# How can I run dev to remote server in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have PhpStorm 2019.3.3. Is it possible to configure in External Tools setting to run `npm run dev` to the remote server?

**Daily routine:**
For example, my web application is residing in the remote server, so every time I will run the npm run dev, I need to ssh to my remote server and cd path to my web app, then run npm run dev.

**Want to automate**

What I want is to setup command like in external tools so that when I run the command name in my local machine it will automatically ssh to my remote server and run npm run dev.

Is this possible or is there another way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by running npm scripts to external server? Is it about using remote Node.js interpreter to run them, or?

Comment: @lena, I updated my post please let me know, thank you

Comment: you can create a shell script that would ssh to your remote server and run `npm run dev` and configure this script as external tool, for example